# What does Enum.GetUnderlyingType(Type) do?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I don't understand the purpose of `Enum.GetUnderlyingType(Type enumType)`

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getunderlyingtype%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) doesn't help either:

> Returns the underlying type of the specified enumeration.

It seems that this converts a specified type of `enum` into... something else. o_O

What *IS* an underlying type? This looks like some internal details of the implementation. Why is this public? Why would I care about the implementation? Browsing the actual implementation doesn't help either, the method just does some checks then calls

```
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)] 
private static extern Type InternalGetUnderlyingType(Type enumType);
```

... to which I can't find the source.

Can anybody shed some light on this?

Comment: Have you read this already? http://dotnetperls.com/enum-getunderlyingtype

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that you can specify the underlying type of an enum via

```
enum Foo : long { One, Two };
```

And then `GetUnderlyingType` is going to return `long` for `typeof(Foo)`.

Note that the underlying type can be any integral type except for `char` types.

Answer (score 7):

Enums are stored in memory as numbers. By default, int32. That's the underlyting type. You can change that:

```
public enum z : byte {
  x = 257 // invalid
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> > Every enumeration type has an underlying type, which can be any integral
> >     type except char. The default underlying type of the enumeration elements is int.

e.g.

```
enum Days {Sat=1, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri};
```

You're underlying type is an int

```
enum Range :long {Max = 2147483648L, Min = 255L};
```

And now it's long.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to an article that gives some explanations about what it does and when to use it.
http://dotnetperls.com/enum-getunderlyingtype